# How do I add permissions from "Azure Service Management" to my app on powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

[Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hsz6.jpg)

See my image for my azure portal. I currently have a permission from "Azure Service Management" titled "user_impersonation". I'm looking to create this same permission on my new application using powershell.

Here's what I use to try to access the "Azure Service Management" service principal, but it doesn't show any app roles.

```
$targetSp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Windows Azure Service Management API'"
$targetSp.AppRoles
```

Anyone know how to grant permissions from this service principal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that, *AppRoles* refers to permissions of **Application** type only. For **Delegated** permissions, you need to use ***Oauth2Permissions***.

In my case, I ran below commands to fetch the ID of **user_impersonation** permission:

```
$targetSp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Windows Azure Service Management API'"
$targetSp.Oauth2Permissions
```

**Response:**

[image]

To add this permission to newly created application, you can make use of below script:

```
$AzureManagementAPI = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.ResourceAccess" -ArgumentList "41094075-9dad-400e-a0bd-54e686782033","Scope"

$RequiredAccess = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.RequiredResourceAccess"
$RequiredAccess.ResourceAppId = "797f4846-ba00-4fd7-ba43-dac1f8f63013"
$RequiredAccess.ResourceAccess = $AzureManagementAPI

$AppName = "Test Application Feb"
$App = New-AzureADApplication -DisplayName $AppName -IdentifierUris "test9" -HomePage "https://yourapphomepage"

Set-AzureADApplication -ObjectId $App.ObjectId -RequiredResourceAccess @($RequiredAccess)
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked in Portal, new application created successfully with **Azure Service Management** API permission like this:

[image]

To grant the **admin consent** to the added permission, you can use below CLI command:

```
az ad app permission admin-consent --id appObjID
```

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where admin consent granted successfully like this:

[image]

To grant the same using PowerShell, refer this blog
[Create and Configure Azure AD Application using PowerShell (morgantechspace.com)](https://morgantechspace.com/2021/03/create-and-configure-azure-ad-application-using-powershell.html) by **Morgan**